# Why does Firebase return an empty array with onSnapshot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get live data from Firebase and I build a listener with onSnapshot so I can display it on my React Native app.

Everything is working fine, like submitting the data to FB.

But when I'm trying to get the data from FB and display it on my React Native app, it's not working.

It's returning an empty array.

When I `console.log(q)` or `console.log(collectionRef)`, it's working perfectly fine. (But not returning the keys ofcourse)

Any help or advice will be much appreciated.

```
export default function Home(){
    const [caretubos, setCaretubos] = React.useState([]);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const collectionRef = collection(database, 'users');
        const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('createdAt','desc'));

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, querySnapshot =>{
        console.log('querySnapshot unsubscribe');
            setCaretubos(
                querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    nombre: doc.data().nombre,
                    cantidad: doc.data().cantidad,
                    pretexto: doc.data().pretexto,
                    createAt: doc.data().createAt
                }))
            );
        });
    return unsubscribe;
    },[])

    console.log(caretubos);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, based on the documentation of `onSnapshot`, that function would only be called when there are updates made to the underlying data after the first snapshot is created.

> You can listen to a document with the onSnapshot() method. An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot.

I recognize that this documentation is ambiguous in interpretation, and it is unclear if immediately creating a snapshot means that your `onSnapshot` callback gets called or if it just means that a "baseline of comparison" is immediately created so that when updates occur, they're known and then the callback can be called.

It sounds like this means that your actual `onSnapshot` callback doesn't get called the first time, but only on updates. You may need to include an initial `setCaretubos` call as well in your effect.:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const collectionRef = collection(database, 'users');
    const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('createdAt','desc'));

    setCaretubos(q.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        nombre: doc.data().nombre,
        cantidad: doc.data().cantidad,
        pretexto: doc.data().pretexto,
        createAt: doc.data().createAt
    }))

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, querySnapshot =>{
        console.log('querySnapshot unsubscribe');
        setCaretubos(
            querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                nombre: doc.data().nombre,
                cantidad: doc.data().cantidad,
                pretexto: doc.data().pretexto,
                createAt: doc.data().createAt
            }))
        );
    });
    return unsubscribe;
},[])
```

Additionally, your `console.log(caretubos);` statement at the bottom will return an empty array the first time before the state is set due to the asynchrony of `useEffect`.

Comment: Thanks Mackers, I just solved it. I had some friction with importing db.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. I had problems with the folder importing stuff.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).